# Django - save data on submit but not reload view

Tags: django

I have a view that display a form that can be saved with a submit button. I dont want the view to be reloaded when the form is submit. However, I have an error if the function do not return a response.

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from ezmapping.models import *
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory

def setAppOptions(request, map_name):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        app_selected = EzApp.objects.get(app_name=app_name, created_by=request.user)
        formset = ezAppOptionFormSet(user=request.user, instance=app_selected)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            formset = ezAppOptionFormSet(request.POST, instance=app_selected, user=request.user)
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()

        return render_to_response("manage_app_options.html", {'formset': formset}, context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 
    else:
        error_msg = u"You are not logged in"
        return HttpResponseServerError(error_msg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do the POST without re-rendering the template, unless you're posting the form via ajax. If you submit the form via ajax and get a response back that is JSON, XML, etc, you can then update the template with the form errors or other information.

However, given the use case outlined in your view, I would suggest limiting access to the view altogether using the [@login_required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator). If you do that, your view logic can be greatly simplified.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Then, is it possible to keep the css state when reloading the page. Example: remember if a fieldset is collapsed or displayed before the submit

Comment: Sure. There are a couple of ways to do that. One would be to persist the value for expanded/collapsed in a hidden field that gets posted with your form, or you could use JavaScript and persist the value in a cookie. Then you can pick the values back up when the page reloads and toggle your fieldsets.

Comment: Would you suggest to use AJAX to post the data without reloading or to use a cookie? My goal is to remember the toggled fielsets after a post.

Comment: I would do everything with one Ajax call. If you really, really want to remember the toggle state of your fieldsets when you navigate away and come back to this page, I would most likely store those in a cookie via JavaScript. If you need a jump start on ajax posts + error handling, etc, take a look at: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2393/