# Prevent reloading after submit button in django

Tags: python, django

I have code written completely in django using get/post method. After submitting the button, it reloads the page. How can I stop reloading the page whenever we are submitting a form?

Comment: With an AJAX call.

Comment: but like for that entire code should be changed?

Comment: Duplicate? [Submit but not reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966985/django-save-data-on-submit-but-not-reload-view)

Comment: till now whenever i am clicking the submit it goes to the post method.Does all the necessary changes and then after the reload the new items gets reloaded.Now I want the same thing but only the new page should not reload.

Comment: This is advisable, since rendering content with `POST` could result in a reload problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to submit form with AJAX. To stop reloading the page you should have to use ajax.
you can follow the link this may solve your problem [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335780/how-to-post-a-django-form-with-ajax-jquery)

Comment: is there any other way to do it .